# Can we create a package in oracle without specification and vice versa

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle package is combination of two parts : The Specification and the Body

in oracle

Can we create a package Specification without body ?

Can we create a package body without specification ?

Answer (score 6):

*Can we create a package Specification without body ?*

Yes, and these are quite useful when the package only contains variable and/or type declarations, e.g.

```
CREATE PACKAGE no_body AS
  gc_yes CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := 'Y';
END;
```

*Can we create a package body without specification ?*

Yes, you can, but it's not very useful as it will be invalid and cannot be used, e.g.:

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY no_spec AS
  PROCEDURE myproc AS BEGIN null; END;
END no_spec;
/
```

The package body won't be usable until you compile a package specification for it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quite simple:

Specification - yes. Body - no (it will be created but will be invalid).

Comment: Yes... [as the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS00901), 'A package always has a specification' and 'If the public items include cursors or subprograms, then the package must also have a body'.